# knockout.js - object data storage best practices

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, field

I'm using knockout js loading a list of jobs from an async service.  Each job has a very long list of fields and I'm wondering if it's considered bad practice to store the data as raw json?

```
function Job(data) {
    var self = this;
    this.data = data; // is this bad practice?

    this.companyName = data.CompanyName; // should I instead list out all the fields?
    this.jobTitle = data.JobTitle;
    // .. 50 more fields
}

function JobsViewModel() {
    function getJobs() {
        $.getJSON(myUrl, { myParams }, function(data) {
            var mappedJobs = $.map(JSON.parse(data.value), function(item) { return new Job(item) });
            self.jobs(mappedJobs);                        
        });
    }

    // initial data load
    getJobs();
}

... // then in my data-bindings
<label data-binding="text: data.CompanyName"></label>
  versus
<label data-binding="text: companyName"></label>
```

The latter is cleaner and more clear, but since I have many fields, I wanted to get some opinions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the knockout mapping plugin. It will generate the properties from your data so you dont have to hand write all of the properties.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

The current approach you are using wont update the label when a property changes in the model because your properties are not observable. Using the mapping plugin will fix this as well.